# Balão que traz as informações sobre a página

Tags: javascript, html

Possuo o seguinte código.

```
<html>
 <table>
  <td>..texto..</td>
 </table>
</html>
```

Gostaria que ao clicar no texto dessa `td` subisse um balão sobre a página e me mostrasse todo conteúdo que essa `td` possui, algo em JS.

Por exemplo imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [Bootstratp](http://getbootstrap.com/) ou [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) Se quiser algo mais específico: [JQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: o nome disso é ToolTip, pesquisa aqui no SOPT que ira achar varias maneiras, ou aguarde que certeza que alguém responde  :)

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp), aprendi com ele e uso ele até hoje, o bom è que não precisa usar livrarias para fazer isso. E è muito simples e super funcional... sua imaginação terminar o processo.

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo que pode usar para um tooltip e o [JavaScript Tooltip](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip)

```js
var tooltipOptions=
{
    showDelay: 20,
    hideDelay: 300,
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 300,
    relativeTo: "element",
    position: 2,
    smartPosition: true,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
    maxWidth: 600,
    calloutSize: 18,
    calloutPosition: 0.5,
    cssClass: "",
    sticky: false,
    overlay: false,
    license: "241l9"
};

/* JavaScript Tooltip v2016.12.12. Copyright www.menucool.com */
var tooltip=function(v){"use strict";var f="length",Cb="addEventListener",kb,mc,fb=function(a,c,b){if(a[Cb])a[Cb](c,b,false);else a.attachEvent&&a.attachEvent("on"+c,b)},a={},Y=function(a){if(a&&a.stopPropagation)a.stopPropagation();else if(window.event)window.event.cancelBubble=true},jc=function(b){var a=b?b:window.event;if(a.preventDefault)a.preventDefault();else if(a)a.returnValue=false},Xb=function(d){var a=d.childNodes,c=[];if(a)for(var b=0,e=a[f];b<e;b++)a[b].nodeType==1&&c.push(a[b]);return c},bb={a:0,b:0},g=null,ec=function(a){if(!a)a=window.event;bb.a=a.clientX;bb.b=a.clientY},bc=function(a){if(window.getComputedStyle)var b=window.getComputedStyle(a,null);else if(a.currentStyle)b=a.currentStyle;else b=a[e];return b},G="offsetLeft",H="offsetTop",pb="clientWidth",ob="clientHeight",z="appendChild",Jb="display",nc="border",r="opacity",U=0,O="createElement",cb="getElementsByTagName",B="parentNode",M="calloutSize",S="position",Db="calloutPosition",D=Math.round,rb="overlay",R="sticky",L="hideDelay",mb="onmouseout",Hb="onclick",n=0,P="firstChild",tb=0,q=document,W="getElementById",Z=navigator,Q="innerHTML",t=function(a,b){return b?q[a](b):q[a]},C={},vb=!!Z.msMaxTouchPoints,V=!!("ontouchstart"in window||window.DocumentTouch&&document instanceof DocumentTouch),Fb=(Z.msPointerEnabled||Z.pointerEnabled)&&vb;if(Fb)var Ub=Z.msPointerEnabled?"onmspointerout":"onpointerOut";var Nb=function(a){return a.pointerType==a.MSPOINTER_TYPE_MOUSE||a.pointerType=="mouse"},lc="marginTop",ic="marginLeft",w="offsetWidth",m="offsetHeight",sb="documentElement",kc="borderColor",gb="nextSibling",e="style",y="width",o="left",p="top",I="height",gc=["$1$2$3","$1$2$3","$1$24","$1$23","$1$22"],x,lb,A=function(c,a,b){return setTimeout(c,a?a.showDelay:b)},eb=function(a){clearTimeout(a);return null},nb=function(){for(var e=[c,b,h,d,d?d[gb]:0],a=0;a<e[f];a++)if(e[a]&&e[a].o)e[a].o=eb(e[a].o)},Lb=function(c,a,b){Gb(c,a[0][0],a[0][1],b);a[f]==2&&Gb(c,a[1][0],a[1][1],b)},Gb=function(a,b,d,c){clearInterval(a["t"+b]);a["t"+b]=setInterval(function(){cc(a,b,d,c)},15)},cc=function(a,d,c,g){var f=0;if(d==r){if(c&&a.op>=1||!c&&a.op<=0)f++}else{var b=parseInt(a[e][d]);if(Math.abs(b-c)<2)f++}if(f){clearInterval(a["t"+d]);g&&g()}else if(d==r)X(a,a.op+(c?.06:-.06));else{b=b+(c-b)/3;if(Math.abs(b-c)<4)b=c;a[e][d]=b+"px"}},l=function(b,a,c){if(n){var d=k?k.duration:v.duration;b[e][n]="all "+d+"ms"}else{b!=h&&Lb(b,a,c);return}b[e][a[0][0]]=a[0][1]+(a[0][0]==r?"":"px");if(a[f]===2)b[e][a[1][0]]=a[1][1]+(a[1][0]==r?"":"px");if(c)if(n){clearTimeout(b.o);b.o=setTimeout(c,d)}else setTimeout(c,6)},J=function(b,a){if(n)b[e][n]="none";b[e][a[0][0]]=a[0][1]+"px";if(a[f]===2)b[e][a[1][0]]=a[1][1]+"px";b[m]},fc=[/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]+$/,/.*([\w\-])\.(\w)(\w)\.[^.]+$/,/^(?:.*\.)?(\w)(\w)\.[^.]+$/,/.*([\w\-])([\w\-])\.com\.[^.]+$/,/^(\w)[^.]*(\w)$/],ib=function(d,a){var c=[];if(tb)return tb;for(var b=0;b<d[f];b++)c[c[f]]=String.fromCharCode(d.charCodeAt(b)-(a&&a>7?a:3));return c.join("")},Kb=function(a){return a.replace(/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])?[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]*$/,"$1$3$2")},Qb=function(e,c){var d=function(a){for(var c=a.substr(0,a[f]-1),e=a.substr(a[f]-1,1),d="",b=0;b<c[f];b++)d+=c.charCodeAt(b)-e;return unescape(d)},a=Kb(q.domain)+Math.random(),b=d(a);lb="%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%20%71%51%28%73%2C%6B%29%7B%76%61%72%20%72%3D%27%27%3B%66%6F%72%28%76%61%72%20%69%";if(b[f]==39)try{a=(new Function("$","_",ib(lb))).apply(this,[b,c]);lb=a}catch(g){}},dc=function(c,a){var b=function(b){var a=b.charCodeAt(0).toString();return a.substring(a[f]-1)};return c+b(a[parseInt(ib("4"))])+a[2]+b(a[0])},c,b,d,ab,h,j,T=0,hc=1,k,E=null,F=function(){if(E!=null)E=eb(E)},X=function(a,b){if(a){a.op=b;if(a[e][r]!==undefined)a[e][r]=b;else a[e].filter="alpha(opacity="+b*100+")"}},Mb=function(a,c,b,d,g,e,h,f){var j=b>=a,l=d>=c,m=j?b-a<g:a-b<h,n=l?d-c<e:c-d<f,i=m?b-a:j?g:-h,k=n?d-c:l?e:-f;if(m&&n)if(Math.abs(i)>Math.abs(k))i=j?g:-h;else k=l?e:-f;return[i,k]},ac=function(r,j,q){db(b,1);var a=t(O,"div");a[e][y]=r+"px";d=t(O,"div");d.className="mcTooltipInner";if(q==1){d[Q]=j;var g=1}else{var c=t(W,j);if(c[B].w)d=c[B];else{d.w=c[B];d[z](c);g=1}}if(!n){var k=d[cb]("select"),l=k[f];while(l--)k[l][mb]=Y}a[z](d);b[z](a);if(d[w]<20){var i=b.className;b.className=""}var h=d[cb]("img");h&&h[f]&&h[0][m];d[e][y]=d[w]+(g?.3:0)+"px";d[e][I]=d[m]+(g?.3:0)+"px";d[e][o]=d[e][p]="auto";d=b.insertBefore(d,b[P]);d[e][S]="absolute";a=b.removeChild(a);a=null;if(i)b.className=i;return d},Ob=function(a){if(a.w){a.w[z](a);X(a,1)}else{a=a[B].removeChild(a);a=null}},db=function(b,c){for(var a=c;a<b.childNodes[f];a++)Ob(b.childNodes[a])},i=function(b,a){b[e][Jb]=a?"block":"none"},Tb=function(){c.v=U=0;i(ab,0);i(c,0);i(h,0);i(T,0);db(b,0)},Sb=function(){if(document.styleSheets&&document.styleSheets.length){var c=document.styleSheets[0];if(typeof b.style.animationName!="undefined")var a="";if(typeof b.style.webkitAnimationName!="undefined")a="-webkit-";else return;var d="@"+a+"keyframes mcttSpinner {from{transform:rotate(0deg);} to{transform:rotate(360deg);}}";c.insertRule(d,0);var e="#tooltipAjaxSpin {margin:30px;font-size:0;width:20px;height:20px;border-width:3px;border-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);border-style:solid;border-top-color:black;border-right-color:rgba(0,0,0,.8);border-radius:50%;"+a+"animation:mcttSpinner .6s linear infinite;}";c.insertRule(e,0)}},s=null,Wb={a:function(d,b,a){var e=null,h=null,i=null,c="html";if(a){h=a.success||null;c=a.responseType||"html";e=a.context&&h?a.context:null;i=a.fail||null}s=this.b();s.onreadystatechange=function(){if(s&&s.readyState===4){if(s.status===200){if(k==d){var j=c.toLowerCase()=="xml"?s.responseXML:s.responseText,l=j;if(c.toLowerCase()=="json")l=eval("("+j+")");if(c=="html"){var o=b.match(/.+#([^?]+)/);if(o){var r=function(e,b){var d=null;if(b.id==e)return b;for(var c=b[cb]("*"),a=0,g=c[f];a<g;a++)if(c[a].id==e){d=c[a];break}return d},n=q[O]("div");n[Q]=j;var m=r(o[1],n);if(m)j=l=m[Q];n=null}if(!m){var p=j.split(/<\/?body[^>]*>/i);if(p[f]>1)j=l=p[1]}}if(h)j=a.success(l,e);g.f(d,j,1)}}else if(i)g.f(d,i(e),1);else g.f(d,"Failed to get data.",1);s=null}};if(b.indexOf("#")!=-1&&Z.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ")!=-1)b=b.replace("#","?#");s.open("GET",b,true);s.send(null)},b:function(){var a;try{if(window.XMLHttpRequest)a=new XMLHttpRequest;else a=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(b){throw new Error("AJAX not supported.");}return a}},Ib=function(){c=t(O,"div");c.id="mcTooltipWrapper";c[Q]='<div id="mcTooltip"><div>&nbsp;</div></div><div id="mcttCo"><b></b></div><div id="mcttCloseButton"></div>';x=q.body;j=x;j[z](c);a.a=v.license||"4321";if(typeof c[e].transition!=="undefined")n="transition";if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome")==-1&&navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari")!=-1)n="webkitTransition";if(!n)c.op=.1;b=c[P];c.b=c.c=c.v=0;Qb(c,a.a);ab=c.lastChild;h=b[gb];i(c,1);this.m(v,1);i(c,0);var f=this.k();kb=function(a){F();f.i();Y(a)};ab[Hb]=kb;this.l();b[mb]=function(){!k[R]&&f.a(k[L])};b[Hb]=Y;fb(b,"touchstart",Y);var d=function(a){if(k&&c.v!==0&&a.target!=k&&k[R]!==1)E=A(function(a){kb(a)},0,k[L]+99);V&&c.v===0&&a.target==k&&k.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mouseover"))};fb(q,"click",d);fb(q,"touchstart",d);X(c,0);c[e].visibility="visible";Pb()},Yb=function(){var b=q.getElementsByTagName("head");if(b[f]){var a=q.createElement("style");b[0].appendChild(a);return a.sheet?a.sheet:a.styleSheet}else return 0},Zb=function(){if(typeof b.style.transform!="undefined")a="";else if(typeof b.style.webkitTransform!="undefined")var a="-webkit-";else if(typeof b.style.msTransform!="undefined")var a="-ms-";else a=0;return a},Bb=function(a){a=a.replace("__",C.prefix);C.a.insertRule(a,0)},Pb=function(){C.prefix=Zb();C.a=Yb();if(C.a){var a="#mcttCloseButton",b="position:absolute;left:auto;cursor:pointer;top:"+v[M]+"px;right:"+v[M]+"px;";if("insertRule"in C.a){Bb(a+"{"+b+"}");Bb("#mcttCloseButton::after{content:'+';display:block;position:absolute;__transform:rotate(45deg);}")}else{C.a.addRule(a,b,0);C.a.addRule("#mcttCloseButton:after","content:'X';display:block;position:absolute;",0)}}},yb=function(a){if(a[B]){var b=a[B].nodeName.toLowerCase();return b!="form"&&b!="body"?yb(a[B]):a[B]}else return x},u=function(c,b){var a=c.getBoundingClientRect();return b?a[p]:a[o]},K=function(b){return b?q[sb][ob]:q[sb][pb]},Vb=function(){var a=q[sb];return[window.pageXOffset||a.scrollLeft,window.pageYOffset||a.scrollTop]},hb=function(c,b,d,f,g){h[e][c?y:I]=a.f*1.55+"px";b[e].webkitTransform=b[e].transform="translate("+f+"px,"+g+"px) rotate("+d+"deg)"},Rb=function(h,g,c,d){var f=K(0),e=K(1),a=0,b=0;if(j!=x){a=u(j,0)-j[G];b=u(j,1)-j[H]}if(c+a+h>f)c=f-h-a;if(c+a<0)c=-a;if(d+b+g>e)d=e-g-b;if(d+b<0)d=-b;return{l:c,t:d}};Ib.prototype={j:function(){if(typeof h[e].transform=="undefined"&&typeof h[e].webkitTransform=="undefined"){h[e][y]="0";return}var b=h[P];h[e][y]=h[e][I]=b[e][y]=b[e][I]=a.f+"px";b[e].borderLeft=b[e].borderTop=a.b+"px solid "+a.d;b[e].backgroundColor=a.c;switch(a.e){case 0:hb(1,b,-135,a.f/4,-a.f/2);break;case 2:hb(1,b,45,a.f/4,a.f/2);break;case 3:hb(0,b,135,-a.f/2,a.f/4);break;default:hb(0,b,-45,a.f/2,a.f/4)}},d:function(a,d,b){F();E=A(function(){(U!=1||a!=c.v)&&g.f(a,d,b)},a)},e:function(a,c,b){F();E=A(function(){g.g(a,c,b)},a)},f:function(f,z,x){i(c,1);U=1;F();nb();i(T,f[rb]);i(ab,f[R]);V&&i(ab,1);var e=this.n(f,z,x);if(c.v){l(c,[[o,e.l],[p,e.t]]);l(b,[[y,b.tw],[I,b.th]]);l(h,[[o,e.x],[p,e.y]])}else if(a.e==4){var A=u(f,0),B=u(f,1);J(c,[[o,A],[p,B]]);l(c,[[o,e.l],[p,e.t]]);l(b,[[y,b.tw],[I,b.th]])}else{J(c,[[p,e.t],[o,e.l]]);J(b,[[y,b.tw],[I,b.th]]);J(h,[[o,e.x],[p,e.y]])}if(f.effect=="slide"){var g,j;if(!c.v&&a.e<4){switch(a.e){case 0:g=0;j=1;break;case 1:g=-1;j=0;break;case 2:g=0;j=-1;break;case 3:g=1;j=0}var k=[g*d[w],j*d[m]]}else{if(!c.v&&a.e>3){g=f[G];j=f[H]}else{g=c[G];j=c[H];if(a.e>3){g+=c.v[G]-f[G];j+=c.v[H]-f[H]}}var t=a.l+a.b+a.b,v=a.m+a.b+a.b;k=Mb(g,j,e.l,e.t,b.b+t,b.c+v,b.tw+t,b.th+v)}var q=a.l/2,s=a.m/2;J(d,[[o,k[0]+q],[p,k[1]+s]]);l(d,[[o,q],[p,s]]);var n=d[gb];if(n){J(n,[[o,q],[p,s]]);l(n,[[o,-k[0]+q],[p,-k[1]+s]],function(){db(b,1)})}X(d,1)}else{l(d,[[r,1]],function(){db(b,1)});var n=d[gb];n&&l(n,[[r,0]])}l(c,[[r,1]]);c.v=f},g:function(a,c,b){s=null;F();!V&&g.f(a,'<div id="tooltipAjaxSpin">&nbsp;</div>',1);Wb.a(a,c,b)},a:function(a){F();E=A(function(){g.i()},0,a)},i:function(){U=-1;nb();l(c,[[r,0]],Tb)},l:function(){if(t(W,"mcOverlay")==null){T=t(O,"div");T.id="mcOverlay";x[z](T);T[e][S]="fixed"}},m:function(f,g){var j=0;if(g||a.e!=f[S]||a.f!=f[M]){a.e=f[S];a.f=f[M];c[e].padding=a.f+"px";j=1}if(g||b.className!=f.cssClass){b.className=f.cssClass?f.cssClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""):"";if(d){d[e][n]="none";d[m]}b[e][n]="none";b[m];var k=bc(b),l=Math.ceil(parseFloat(k.borderLeftWidth)),p=k.backgroundColor,o=k.borderLeftColor;if(g||a.b!=l||a.c!=p||a.d!=o){a.b=l;a.c=p;a.d=o;j=1}a.l=g?b[pb]-b[P][w]:d[G]*2;a.m=g?b[ob]-b[P][m]:d[H]*2}if(j)if(a.e<4)this.j();else i(h,0)},k:function(){return(new Function("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i",function(e){var d=[];b.onmouseover=function(a){if(!k[R]){F();if(U==-1){nb();l(c,[[r,1]])}}Y(a)};for(var a=0,g=e[f];a<g;a++)d[d[f]]=String.fromCharCode(e.charCodeAt(a)-4);return d.join("")}("zev$pAi,k,g,+kvthpu+0405--\u0080\u0080+6+-?zev$qAe2e\u0080\u0080+55+0rAtevwiMrx,q2glevEx,4--0sA,,k,g,+kvthpu+0405--\u0080\u0080+px+-2vitpegi,h_r16a0l_r16a--2wtpmx,++-?mj,e2e%Aj,r/+8+0s--qAQexl_g,+yhukvt+-a,-?mj,q@259-wixXmqisyx,jyrgxmsr,-m,40g,+Ch'oylmD.o{{wA66~~~5tlu|jvvs5jvt6.E[vvs{pw'W|yjohzl'YltpuklyC6hE+-0tswmxmsr>:\u0081-?\u008106444-?\u0081\u0081vixyvr$xlmw?"))).apply(this,[a,P,ib,fc,Kb,dc,t,gc,jb])},n:function(k,C,u){var q=x;if(u==2){var D=t(W,C),B=D[cb]("*"),E=B[f];while(E--)if(B[E].type=="submit")q=yb(D)}if(j!=q){j=q;j[z](c)}b.b=b[pb]-a.l;b.c=b[ob]-a.m;d=ac(k.maxWidth,C,u);this.m(k,0);if(!n)d[e].backgroundColor=a.c;b.tw=d[w];b.th=d[m];k.effect=="fade"&&X(d,0);var s=b.tw+a.l+a.b+a.b,r=b.th+a.m+a.b+a.b,o=this.p(k,s,r);if(k.smartPosition)var g=Rb(s+a.f,r+a.f,o.x,o.y);else g={l:o.x,t:o.y};var l=k[S],p=this.u(l,k[Db],s,r);if(k.smartPosition&&l<4){var y=g.l-o.x,A=g.t-o.y;if(l==0||l==2)p[0]-=y;else y&&i(h,0);if(l==1||l==3)p[1]-=A;else A&&i(h,0)}if(j==x){var v=Vb();g.l=g.l+v[0];g.t=g.t+v[1]}g.x=p[0];g.y=p[1];return g},p:function(b,t,s){var c,d,h,g,p=b[S],n=b[Db];if(p<4)if(b.nodeType!=1)c=d=h=g=0;else if(b.relativeTo=="mouse"){c=bb.a;d=bb.b;if(bb.a==null){c=u(b,0)+D(b[w]/2);d=u(b,1)+D(b[m]/2)}h=0;g=0}else{var i=b,e=Xb(b);if(e[f]){e=e[0];if(e[w]>=b[w]||e[m]>=b[m])i=e}c=u(i,0);d=u(i,1);h=i[w];g=i[m]}var o=20,l=t+2*b[M],k=s+2*b[M];switch(p){case 0:c+=D(h/2-l*n);d-=k+o;break;case 2:c+=D(h/2-l*n);d+=g+o;break;case 3:c-=l+o;d+=D(g/2-k*n);break;case 4:c=D((K(0)-l)/2);d=D((K(1)-k)/2);break;case 5:c=d=0;break;case 6:c=K(0)-l-Math.ceil(a.l/2);d=K(1)-k-Math.ceil(a.m/2);break;case 1:default:c+=h+o;d+=D(g/2-k*n)}var q=0,r=0;if(j!=x){q=j[G]-u(j,0);r=j[H]-u(j,1)}return{x:c+q+b.offsetX,y:d+r+b.offsetY}},u:function(f,c,e,d){i(h,f<4);var b=[0,0];switch(f){case 0:b=[e*c,d+a.f-a.b-1];break;case 1:b=[a.b+.5,d*c];break;case 2:b=[e*c,a.b];break;case 3:b=[e+a.f-a.b-1,d*c]}return b}};var zb=function(){if(g==null){if(typeof console!=="undefined"&&typeof console.log==="function"){var a=console.log;console.log=function(){a.call(this,++tb,arguments)}}g=new Ib;if(a)console.log=a;Sb()}if(k&&k.m&&c[Q].indexOf(ib("kdvh#Uh"))!=-1)g.i=function(){};return g},ub=function(d,c,b){b=b||{};var a;for(a in c)d[a]=b[a]!==undefined?b[a]:c[a]},qb=0,N,Eb=function(a){if(!a){a=t(O,"div");a.m=1;a[e][Jb]="none";x[z](a)}if(typeof a==="string")a=t(W,a);k=a;return a},wb=function(a,b){ub(a,v,b);if(vb||V){a.showDelay=1;a[L]=30}if(a[rb])a[R]=a[rb];if(!a[R])if(Fb)a[Ub]=function(a){Nb(a)&&g.a(this[L])};else a[mb]=function(){E=A(function(){g.a(a[L])},0,V?400:a[L]+200)};if(a.relativeTo=="mouse")a.onmousemove=ec;a.set=1},jb=function(a,c,h){a=Eb(a);var b=0;if(c.charAt(0)=="#"){if(c[f]>2&&c.charAt(1)=="#")b=2;else b=1;var d=c.substring(b),e=t(W,d);if(e){if(b==2)c=e[Q]}else b=-1}if(!a||!g||b==-1){if(++qb<40)N=A(function(){jb(a,c,h)},0,90)}else{N=eb(N);!a.set&&wb(a,h);if(b==1)g.d(a,d,2);else g.d(a,c,1)}},xb=function(a,d,b,c){a=Eb(a);if(!a||!g){if(++qb<40)N=A(function(){xb(a,d,b,c)},0,90)}else{N=eb(N);!a.set&&wb(a,c);g.e(a,d,b)}};fb(window,"load",zb);var Ab=function(a){if(++qb<20)if(!g)A(function(){Ab(a)},0,90);else{ub(v,v,a);i(c,1);g.m(v,0);i(c,0)}};return{changeOptions:function(L_options){Ab(L_options)},pop:function(L_sender,L_text,L_options){jb(L_sender,L_text,L_options)},ajax:function(L_sender,L_url,L_ajaxSettings,L_options){xb(L_sender,L_url,L_ajaxSettings,L_options)},hide:function(){var a=zb();a.i()}}}(tooltipOptions)
```

```css
/* www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip */

/*For tooltip target element that has set class="tooltip" */
.tooltip {text-decoration: none; border-bottom:1px dotted #36c;color: #36c; outline:none; }

/*For tooltip box*/
#mcTooltip 
{
    line-height:16px;
    border: 1px solid #333; 
    color:#000; 
    padding:20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    border-radius:1px;
    background-color:white;
}

#mcTooltip, #mcttCo b {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

/* For hyperlink within tooltip */
#mcTooltip a { color:#36c; }

/*Close button. Available when sticky or overlay has been set to true, or is on touch-enabled devices. */
#mcttCloseButton
{ 
    width:18px;
    height:18px;
    margin-right:4px;
    margin-top:4px; 
}
/*Close button X symbol*/
#mcttCloseButton:after {
    font:normal 38px/18px arial, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    top:0;left:-2px;
}

/*Give the close button a bigger size on smaller devices*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) {
    #mcttCloseButton {
        width:28px;
        height:28px;
    }
    #mcttCloseButton:after {
        font-size:48px;
        line-height:28px;
    }    
} 

/* Useful when overlay has been set to true or 1 in JS */
#mcOverlay 
{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    display:none;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height: 100%;overflow:visible;z-index:4; 
}
#mcTooltip img {border:0;vertical-align:middle;}

/*The settings below should remain unchanged*/
#mcTooltipWrapper {position:absolute;visibility:hidden;overflow:visible;z-index:9999999999;top:-2000px;}
#mcTooltip {float:left;border-style:solid;position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.mcTooltipInner {float:left;position:relative;width:auto;height:auto;}
#mcttCo,  #mcttCo b{position:absolute;overflow:hidden;}

/*compatible with bootstrap*/
#mcTooltip, #mcTooltip div {box-sizing:content-box;}
```

```html
<span class="tooltip" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, '<strong>Nome Nome Nome </strong><span> Descrição<br/><p>Qualque conteudo html</p></span>', {position:0})">
    Passe o mouse aqui
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) e o [Bootstrap JS Modal](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp), que é um "plugin" do [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.abrir-modal').on('click', AbrirModal);

  function AbrirModal() {
    var codigo = $(this).data('codigo');

    $('#myModal').modal();
    $('#myModal .modal-title').html('Código selecionado: ' + codigo);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Primeiro</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="abrir-modal" data-codigo="1">Link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Segundo</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="abrir-modal" data-codigo="2">Link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">
        
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Com foundation não teria nada ?

Comment: Nunca usei o Foundation. Mas com certeza deve ter algo, só dar uma procurada.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

O Bootstrap tem algumas coisas em relação à tooltips e popovers.

Você disse que quer que o usuário clique para aparecer, veja:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Título do popover" data-content="Conteúdo do popover">Clique</button>
```

Pode ver ler mais sobre os popovers [aqui](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/). Além do popover tem as [tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips), que já comentaram acima.

Answer (score 0):

O script abaixo em JS puro e sem uso de bibliotecas faz o mesmo efeito.

**Funcionamento simples:** clique numa célula da `<table>` e abrirá o box com o texto da célula clicada (e fechar o box de outra célula caso esteja aberta). Clique fora da tabela para fechar o box.

```js
tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(x=0;x<tds.length;x++){
 tds[x].addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(!this.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]){
   escondeTudo();
   this.setAttribute("style", "position: relative;");
   td_texto = this.innerHTML;
   seta = document.createElement('span');
   seta.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;bottom: 80%;left: 50%;margin-left: -8px;width: 0;height: 0;border-top: 8px solid #bbb;border-right: 8px solid transparent;border-left: 8px solid transparent;");
   seta.setAttribute("class", "pops");
   this.appendChild(seta);
   ptexto = document.createElement('p');
   ptexto.innerHTML = td_texto;
   ptexto.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;bottom: 52%;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,0);-moz-transform:translate(-50%,0);transform:translate(-50%,0);left:50%; max-width: 200px; display: inline-block; padding: 5px; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #ddd; text-align:center;border-radius:10px;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.48);-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.48);box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.48);");
   ptexto.setAttribute("class", "pops");
   this.appendChild(ptexto);
  }

  e.stopPropagation();return false;

 });
}

function escondeTudo(){
 apaga_pops = document.getElementsByClassName("pops");
 while(apaga_pops[0]){
  apaga_pops[0].parentNode.removeChild(apaga_pops[0]);
 }
}

document.addEventListener("click",function(){
 escondeTudo();
});
```

```html
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<table style="margin-left: 100px;" cellpadding="5">
 <tr>
  <td>..texto1..</td>
  <td>Latest compiled and minified JavaScript</td>
  <td>..texto3..</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```